# drupal redirecting api

Tags: api, drupal, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect this the request for "homebox/1" to "homebox/1/[uid]" if a logged in user tries to access it. I do not care about annonymous users at this point yet.

This is the code I put into the top page-homebox.tpl.php:

```
if(!is_numeric(arg(2))){
global $user;
if($user->uid){
    if(count($_GET) > 1){
        $get = array();
        foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
            if($k != 'q')
                $get[] = $k.'='.$v;
        }
        $get2 = '?'.implode('&',$get);
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('location:/homebox/1/'.$user->uid.$get2);
}else{
    //redirect to error page
}
}
```

However, do the *.tpl.php files get processed late in the request? In that case I am doing it rather inefficiently.

I know about the path redirect module(http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect). I don't want to use that because I'd like to learn whether there are any Drupal API for redirecting and/or methods to catch and redirect the request right at the beginning of the processing chain.

Thanks
Arul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have had to use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu_alter) but it looks like the homebox_menu() function dosn't define an entry for homebox/

So you would just write your own [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu) implementation whih matches homebox/ and define a callback and put your logic in there.

You will probably want to user [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto) to do the redirect itself.

Well done for looking to remove such logic from the template.